# Why does adding an observer to react-query cause it to ignore its `enabled` property?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

**Update: I've now filed this as an issue over on react-query's Github, you should probably follow it [there](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/issues/2502).**

I have a pretty straightforward `useQuery`:

```js
const refreshable = false // hard coded for the sake of example
const tokenQuery = useQuery('refresh-token', refreshQueryFn, {
  enabled: refreshable,
  refetchInterval: 1000 * 30,
  refetchIntervalInBackground: true,
})
```

If this is stand-alone then no problems. Everything initialises, and unless `refreshable` is set `true` then it lies dormant.

However, in the same hook I added an observer...

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // Create an observer to watch the query and update its result into state
  const observer = new QueryObserver(queryClient, {
    queryKey: 'refresh-token',
  })
  const unsubscribe = observer.subscribe((queryResult) => {
    console.log(
      'Do something with the token!'
      queryResult.data
    )
  })

  // Clean up the subscription when the component unmounts
  return () => {
    unsubscribe()
  }
}, [token, queryClient])
```

**Attaching the observer causes a fetch (and failure, and multiple retries) to happen irrespective of `enabled`, which I don't think should happen.**

Can anyone explain why this happens, before I raise an issue on react-query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

under the hood, useQuery creates a QueryObserver with the options you pass to it. So after the userQuery, you'll have one observer with enabled: false, which will give you a disabled query.

Now enabled is a per-observer property. It is totally legit to have one useQuery instance that is enabled while having another with the same queryKey that is disabled.

And this is basically what you are doing: When you manually create the new QueryObserver, you are not passing enabled: false to it, so you create a second observer that is enabled, which will then run the query.

So passing `refreshable` to the new Oberver's `enabled` option should solve it:

```
const observer = new QueryObserver(queryClient, {
  queryKey: 'refresh-token',
  enabled: refreshable,
})
```